# Delete cascade across junction tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have 3 tables defined as

```
Product = ProductID, ProductTitle, ProductStatus
Category = CategoryID, CategoryTitle
ProductInCategory = ProductID, CategoryID
```

`ProductInCategory.ProductID` is a FK of `Product.ProductID`, and `ProductInCategory.CategoryID` is a FK of `Category.CategoryID`.

At the moment, the on delete cascade deletes the relationship if either a Product or a Category are deleted, how would i go about having this cascade then move across the junction table? I.e. if i delete a category, delete all products that were associated with that category via the junction table **without** manually deleting each product myself.

Comment: Surely, if that's a true junction table (many-to-many) you don't want to "delete all products that were associated with that category" - wouldn't you maybe only want to delete those products which are no longer associated with *any* category?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trigger on the ProductInCategory table would work:

```
DROP TRIGGER remove_products
GO
CREATE TRIGGER remove_products
ON ProductInCategory
FOR DELETE
AS 
DELETE FROM Product WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID FROM deleted);
GO
```

As deletes already cascade from Category to ProductInCategory this trigger should remove the associated products as well. I assume you don't want to remove categories when deleting from the Product table.